# How to make the Terminal make a noise on command completion?

Tags: command-line, gnome, sound, gnome-terminal

Let's say I run a command which takes a long time to do its stuff, but I don't want or need to look at it the whole time, and as I need to do some other stuff as well I might get into that and forget to check on how the command is doing for some time... Then when I finally do check I may find that the command finished 3 hours ago and needed my attention then... Or perhaps it didn't need my attention, if I had seen that it had finished at the time I would have had more time to run more commands...

So I was wondering if there is a way to get it so that when a command or program has been run, whenever it finishes and returns to `$`, for it to make a little sound, like play an mp3 file or something? Though it would be acceptable just to get this working in `gnome-terminal`, I would like it in as many CLI environments as possible including the TTYs if that would be possible... I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18.

Comment: As for the duplicate question, pcspkr is disabled on newer versions of *Ubuntu* (works fine on debian and other linux distros) and so does not work unless you remove pcspkr from the blacklist and/or modprobe pcspkr.

Comment: @mchid do consider editing it.

Comment: I found out how to get it to automatically beep after each command is run. I updated the answer and it is located after **EDIT**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, run the following commands to enable `pcspkr` and to install `beep`:

```
sudo sed -i 's/blacklist pcspkr/#blacklist pcspkr/g' /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
sudo modprobe pcspkr
sudo apt-get install beep
```

Now, run a command along with `beep` like so:

```
sudo apt-get update; beep
```

or

```
sudo apt-get update; beep;beep;beep;beep;beep
```

Finally, to control the volume of `beep`, change the `beep` volume from `alsamixer` by running the following command:

```
alsamixer
```

Now, use your right arrow key to scroll to the automute option. Use the up arrow to toggle this off.

Then use the left arrow key to scroll to beep and use the up or down arrow key to raise or lower the volume of beep.

Use the <kbd>M</kbd> key to mute or un-mute any channel.

Press <kbd>ESC</kbd> to exit `alsamixer`

Many more options for beep can be found at:

```
man beep
```

---

**EDIT**

Now, to get the terminal to beep after each command is run, run the following command:

```
cp .bashrc .bashbackup
echo 'PROMPT_COMMAND="beep"' | tee -a .bashrc
. .bashrc
```

Comment: Can one use aliases or something to make it after every command without having to manually type `beep` after a command?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda I was thinking about that and I'm not sure. I think you might be able to add it by using $1 somehow but I'm not sure.

Comment: Well, if you ever do find out be sure to edit your answer and then ping me! ;)

Comment: @ParanoidPanda Just do an `alias aub="sudo apt-get update; beep"`

Comment: @ParanoidPanda In case you didn't get notified, I added an edit so that you don't have to type beep after every command.

Comment: alsamixer does not show a beeper volume, but beep is working (loudly)